# Arcpy describe raster colormap

Tags: arcpy, raster, colormap

Does anyone know a way to use `arcpy.describe` to see if there is a colormap on a raster? Can't find anything in the help.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question, you need to provide a bit more detail such as which format are your datasets, mixed or a single type?

If you look at the help page titled *[Supported raster dataset file formats](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009t0000000q000000)* this lists all the raster ArcGIS supports, it has a column that indicates if it supports colour maps.

So first logic is that if it is a raster of type *X* you can immediately say it definitely does not have a colour map. Then if you read the help on the tool *[Add Colormap (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000009w000000)* under the usage section it also emphasises other limitations. So any raster that is a float cannot have a colour map.

According to help it says:

> "For Esri Grid files, the color map information is stored in a .clr
>   file with the same name. For most other formats, the color map is
>   embedded within the raster dataset."

So if your data is an ESRI grid format you could search for the .clr file?

Having looked at the object model of arcpy I cannot see any way of asking the question does it have a colour map?

If you have VBA installed you can run this macro and it will list which rasters have a colour map in the current MXD.

```vb
Public Sub HasColourMap()
    ' Created: 16/2/15 (Duncan Hornby)

    ' Get Map document
    Dim pMXD As IMxDocument
    Set pMXD = ThisDocument

    ' Get current map
    Dim pMap As IMap
    Set pMap = pMXD.FocusMap

    ' Get an enumerate over raster layers in map document
    Dim pUID As UID
    Set pUID = New UID
    pUID.Value = "{D02371C7-35F7-11D2-B1F2-00C04F8EDEFF}"
    Dim pEnumLayer As IEnumLayer
    Set pEnumLayer = pMap.Layers(pUID)

    ' Declare some objects
    Dim pLayer As ILayer
    Dim pRasterLayer As IRasterLayer
    Dim pRaster As IRaster
    Dim pRasterBandCollection As IRasterBandCollection
    Dim pRasterBand As IRasterBand

    ' main loop
    Set pLayer = pEnumLayer.Next
    Do While Not pLayer Is Nothing
        ' Get raster and extract out the first band. Code is assuming input rasters are integer
        Set pRasterLayer = pLayer
        Set pRaster = pRasterLayer.Raster
        Set pRasterBandCollection = pRaster
        Set pRasterBand = pRasterBandCollection.Item(0)

        ' Test if it has a colourmap
        If Not pRasterBand.Colormap Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print pRasterLayer.Name & " : has colour map"
        Else
            Debug.Print pRasterLayer.Name & " : no colour map"
        End If

        ' Get next layer
        Set pLayer = pEnumLayer.Next
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Well the datasets I am looking at are all a format that can have colormaps and no I don't have VBA installed. The level of effort for getting that up and working isn't worth it to me. I am just really surprised there isn't a way to find this info... I mean it is listed on the properties for each raster dataset. Anyways thanks for the info but I am still leaving this question open.